# SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 VS2013.4

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2014

I use VS2013.4 for my web application. Together with VS there is buildin SQL server 2014 installed as well.

I am trying to use membership for web credential and CreateUser tool for loging. I am not sure if I need any SQL server additional setup because every time I try to register new user in new project I recive error:

```
provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26
```

The APP_DATA folder is created but the database does not appear.

Do I need SQL server management studio?

Why Do I need instance? Shoouldn't it all be done inside VS2013? The mdf shouldn't be created it appdata folder?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue when the application cannot locate the instanceFollow the steps as defined on the link below to Isolate the issue

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-server-instance-specified.aspx

You need the sql server management studio to be able to start your instance services if needed. It's much easier

Comment: Why Do I need instance? Shoouldn't it all be done inside VS2013? The mdf shouldn't be created it appdata folder?

Comment: Mssql databases occur in an instance so to connect to a database you have to connect first to the instance and then the database